# Issues with simulating a seasonal ARIMA model

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to generate simulations from a seasonal arima model using the forecast package in R via the following command:

```
simulate(model_temp)
```

where `model_temp` is the result of applying the `arima()` function to my observed time series, and with which, incidentally, I specified the model to be an ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,1,2)[12] model.

However, when I attempt this, I get the following error:

```
Error in diffinv.vector(x, lag, differences, xi) :
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Can anybody please explain why this is the case (and how to avoid this problem)?

I should further add, that I know that the model that I applied and resulting in the fit of `model_temp` is not the model that generated the series, but nevertheless, I would still like to generate simulations from that model (or any other model for that matter).

Lastly, is it possible to generate simulations from a seasonal ARIMA model by just specifying the ar, d, ma, sar, sd, sma and sigma parameters and without having first created an object of the correct ARIMA type?

Thank you for any help,

Jonathan

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you have missing values,
as in the following example.

```
library(forecast)
x <- WWWusage
x[10] <- NA
fit <- Arima(x,c(3,1,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=12))
simulate(fit) # Fails
```

The default arguments simulate future values conditional 
on the data, and fails if some values are missing. 
If you want an unrelated sample, you can add `future=FALSE`.

```
simulate(fit, future=FALSE) # Does not fail
```

To simulate from an arbitrary model, you can try to
build a minimal `Arima` object,
with only the data needed.

```
m <- list(
  arma=c(3,0,0,1,12,1,1),
  model=list(
    phi=c(1.17, -0.71, 0.39),
    theta=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-.79)
  ),
  sigma2=11,
  x=NA
)
simulate.Arima(m, nsim=30, future=FALSE)
```

Comment: there are difference in using `simulate` or `arima.sim` ?

Comment: @tyranitar: The main difference is the `future` argument: `simulate` can generate data conditional on data that has already been observed, i.e., sample from the continuations of the data. But if there is no observed data, they should give the same result: `simulate` just calls `arima.sim`.