# Simulating a basic sarima model in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, simulation

I'm looking for something like

```
   arima.sim()
```

but for sarima models.  I've looked at simulate.Arima() in the forecast package, but it seems to require an input dataset parsed by Arima(), which I don't want to do.  I also looked at the gsarima library, but it seems to be only able to simulate seasonal AR models.  Is there any way to simulate a sarima model if you only want to provide the following information:

1. The values of all pure ARMA and seasonal ARMA terms for different lags.
2. The number of differences for both the seasonal and non-seasonal integrated terms.
3. The length of a season.
4. The number of terms I want to simulate.

Comment: What about creating your own function?

Comment: I could do that, but I was wondering if there was any function already created, partly so I could direct other people to it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561345/144157